# Why Application#call is running so slow in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a standard Rails 4.1 Application with a Grape on top providing API.

Recently I found that `Application#call` has taken quite a big part of my response time, following is what I see in `Newrelic`:

[image]

`Maleskine::Application#call` takes the largest part, 67.6ms and 29.8% of the average response time. I don't think this is right, is it? But I don't know where to look at.

I need help, Thank you very much.

Comment: It may be cause of POST request.One possible cause of the longer timings is that Rack::MethodOverride needs to examine the request body on POST in order to determine whether the POST parameters contain a method override See that answer [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24639701/random-slow-rackmethodoverridecall-on-rails-app-on-heroku)